# DirectX Collision(AABB)

Tags: c++, directx

I've been trying to apply Axis-Aligned Bounding Boxes to my cubes in DX11.

So far, I have a `UserInput` Class which holds all of the variables for each cube, xPos, yPos, zPos, Rotation etc.

In the UserInput, I have a function that checks whether the two objects are colliding.

```
class UserInput
{
public:
    float xPos[2];
    float yPos[2];
    float zPos[2];
    Vector3 vecMin;
    Vector3 vecMax;
    float rotationX;
    float rotationY;
    float rotationZ;
    bool isMoving;
    bool isMovingRight;
    bool isMovingLeft;
    bool isMovingUp;
    bool isMovingDown;
    bool isMovingCloser;
    bool isMovingFurther;
    bool isRotatingX;
    bool isRotatingY;
    bool isRotatingZ;
    UserInput()
    {
        xPos[0] = -1.5f;
        yPos[0] = 0.0f;
        zPos[0] = 0.0f;
        xPos[1] = 1.5f;
        yPos[1] = 0.0f;
        zPos[1] = 0.0f;
        vecMin.x = -1.0f;
        vecMax.x = 1.0f;
        vecMin.y = -1.0f;
        vecMax.y = 1.0f;
        vecMin.z = -1.0f;
        vecMax.z = 1.0f;
        rotationX = 0.0f;
        rotationY = 0.0f;
        rotationZ = 0.0f;
        isMovingRight = false;
        isMovingLeft = false;
        isMovingUp = false;
        isMovingDown = false;
        isMovingCloser = false;
        isMovingFurther = false;
        isRotatingX = false;
        isRotatingY = false;
        isRotatingZ = false;
    }

    //Collision Rejection Test
    bool Collision(const UserInput& box1, const UserInput& box2)
    {
        return !(
            box1.vecMin.x > box2.vecMax.x ||
            box1.vecMax.x < box2.vecMin.x ||
            box1.vecMin.y > box2.vecMax.y ||
            box1.vecMax.y < box2.vecMin.y ||
            box1.vecMin.z > box2.vecMax.z ||
            box1.vecMax.z < box2.vecMin.z
            );
    }
};
```

I have two functions that essentially make the scene, Update & Render. In the update function, I have this following line of code

```
input->Collision(input[0], input[1]);
```

Which should check the collision each time it updates.

Each cube is drawn and rendered like this

```
    //Update variables for the first cube
ConstantBuffer cb1;
cb1.mWorld = XMMatrixTranspose(g_World);
cb1.mView = XMMatrixTranspose(g_View);
cb1.mProjection = XMMatrixTranspose(g_Projection);
cb1.LightDir = LightDirs;
cb1.LightColour = LightColours;
cb1.OutputColour = XMFLOAT4(0, 0, 0, 0);
g_pImmediateContext->UpdateSubresource(g_pConstantBuffer, 0, nullptr, &cb1, 0, 0);


//Render first cube
g_pImmediateContext->VSSetShader(g_pVertexShader, nullptr, 0);
g_pImmediateContext->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &g_pConstantBuffer);
g_pImmediateContext->PSSetShader(g_pPixelShader, nullptr, 0);
g_pImmediateContext->PSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &g_pConstantBuffer);
g_pImmediateContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &g_Texture);
g_pImmediateContext->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &g_TextureSamplerState);
g_pImmediateContext->DrawIndexed(36, 0, 0);
```

But I cannot seem how to work out how to 'attach' the boxes with the cubes.
So obviously, so far the cubes just pass through each other with nothing colliding.

Comment: The trick with the AABBs (i.e. why collision check is that simple and fast) is that they don't have rotation. If you want to rotate your cubes, the AABBs have to become respectively larger. In this case, the latter will include of course a lot of "air" but this is the price for the speed. (Hence, AABBs are usually used as a pre-decision which are followed by more sophisiticated checks in case of AABB collision detection.)

Comment: To compute AABBs from a rotated cube, you could e.g. determine all 8 corner points for the rotated cube, and get min/max for x, y, z components separately to form the corresponding AABB.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with directx. g_World matrix has a transformation of your cube and you must update it accordingly.

Comment: Take a look at [DirectXMath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dxmath/directxmath-portal) which has collision types including [aabb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/DirectXCollision/ns-directxcollision-boundingbox).